# Git rebase issue with files of same name but different case

Tags: git

I am fairly new to Git, and I am having a problem with doing a rebase, where it seems to show a file...

create.sql

and a file

Create.sql

The Create.sql is not staged, and does not physically exist anymore, but I cannot continue with the rebase... when I try git rebase --continue I get the following...

```
$ git rebase --continue
KeyBlade/KeyBlade.Database/_Pending/Create.sql: needs update
You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add
```

Git status show the following...

```
/c/src/git ((c3760e6...)|REBASE)
$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   KeyBlade/KeyBlade.Database/_Pending/create.sql
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   KeyBlade/KeyBlade.Database/_Pending/Create.sql
#
```

I am not sure what is going on, but if anyone can shed some light on how I can resolve this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which OS and filesystem are you using?

Comment: I am using Windws 7 - NTFS file system

Answer (score 17, accepted):

for anyone else that has this issue I found a post at the following site...

[https://tortoisegit.org/issue/830](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=830)

In a nutshell, if you had a file name foo.txt and then it conflicts with a file called Foo.txt, you can use the following git command

git mv foo.txt Foo.txt --force

This solved my problem

Comment: If you get a case error in future you can run the following git command... git config --global core.ignorecase true

Comment: The issue link is now dead, it looks like you can find it [here](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/issues/830).