# Downloading multiple reactive objects containing data tables

Tags: r, shiny

I have multiple tables in reactive objects in my shiny app `(RA_s,Per)`, and I download each separately. Now, I'm trying to download one zip file containing all of this tables using a download button.

Here is my code, I don't know how to complete `downloadHandler` function. I want to download a zip file which contain 2 csv files `RA_s` and `Per`.

**Code**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  RA_s <- reactive({
    iris
  })

  Per <- reactive({
    sepal1 <- RA_s()["Sepal_Length"]
    sepal2 <- RA_s()["Sepal_Width"]
    value = sepal1*sepal2
    c = cbind(RA_s(),value)
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste0("output", ".zip")
  },
  content = function(file) {
  ...
  })
})


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Download", tabName = "d")
)
body<- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "d",
         downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
     )
  )
dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Valo"),
sidebar,
body
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first save the zip files, and then zip them, as follows:

```
library(shiny)
server<- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  RA_s <- reactive({
    iris
    print(iris)
  })

  Per <- reactive({
    sepal1 <- RA_s()["Sepal.Length"]
    sepal2 <- RA_s()["Sepal.Width"]
    value = sepal1*sepal2
    c = cbind(RA_s(),value)
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = 'two_csvs.zip',
    content = function(fname) {

      write.csv(RA_s(), file = "csv1.csv", sep =",")
      write.csv(Per(), file = "csv2.csv", sep =",")

      zip(zipfile=fname, files=c("csv1.csv","csv2.csv"))
    },
    contentType = "application/zip"
  )

})

ui<- shinyUI(

  downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')

)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

You can specify a subdirectory of course, to keep your directory clean. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Florian it works very well. How can i specify a directory in which i want to save my zip file ?

Comment: You can specify the directory for your csv's by doing `write.csv(RA_s(), file = "dirname/csv1.csv", sep =",")`, where dirname should be the name of your directory. Please note that the directory has to exist for that to work! You can create a folder 'storage' in the same folder as your ui.R and server.R for example. Please consider accepting my answer if it was helpful, thanks!

Comment: I still have a little problem. In addition to the zip file, the csv files are also downloaded separatly in my working directory

Comment: I think they are created because of the write.csv statements. Did you create an additional folder in your working directory and adjust the write csv statements as per my previous comments?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work. i have this error : 'Error : cannot open the connection'

Comment: There are many answers to that question on Stack Overflow. Probably you are trying to write to a non-existent directory. [maybe this helps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604351/error-cannot-open-the-connection-in-r-shiny)