# Change name file not updated in GIT

Tags: git

I have a file called member.java" I committed and pushed this file using GIT. After that I changed the name to Member.java (M Uppercase) -- however every time I want to commit the file GIT write it member.java (m in lowercase) ...

[image]

How can I resolve this problem ? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793735/change-case-of-a-file-on-windows

Comment: If the two answers posted didn't solve your problem, please try renaming the file as you normally do then post the output of the status command `git status`. Then, run the command `git add Member.java` and post the output of running the status command again `git status`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in two ways

- `git mv -f member.java Member.java`

Or, If ignore case option is available in your git version

- If you would like to do this for one project, run this from project directory `git config core.ignorecase true`
- If you would like to do this for all project then `git config --global core.ignorecase true`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you are using git 2.0 or more in your IDE. (see "[Changing capitalization of filenames in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/6309)").
IntelliJ, for instance, checks [the OS vs. its case sensitive policy](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Filesystem+Case-Sensitivity+Mismatch).
To be sure, fall back to command line (with git for Windows 2.9.2) and do a

```
git mv member.java Member.java
```

(no need for `git mv --force` anymore)

Add, commit then switch back to your IDE: check after a refresh it does reflect the case change.

---

IntelliJ has an interresting blog post last month: "[How to Support Case-only Rename in Git](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/06/how-to-support-case-only-rename-in-git/)"

> Things got really interesting when we tried to commit these rename changes, which were already properly recognized by Git.
>   In Git CLI, as well as in most of the clients, you just call `git commit` and commit everything that is staged.
>   **However, in IntelliJ IDEA we call `git commit --only -- <paths>` which lets commit only selected files, regardless of whether they are staged or not**. This allows you, the user, to select paths from the UI and not think about Git indexes.
>
> **The problem here is that Git doesn’t allow the --only syntax for case-only renames**, so `git commit --only MyClass.java Myclass.java` simply fails

You would need the recent [IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 EAP](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/06/intellij-idea-2016-2-eap-case-only-renames-in-git-ligatures-background-images-and-more/) (June 2016) to benefit from their workaround allowing you to rename files in a case-insensitive (but case-preserving) OS environment.

It finally solves [issue IDEA-53175](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-53175) (March 2010).