# Ruby-heroku No default language could be detected for this app

Tags: ruby, heroku

I want to use Heroku for my Ruby apps (not on Rails).

I wrote a Twitch chat bot but I can't deploy it.

Here is the code: https://github.com/sydneyfunnelAIO/sydneybt

I tried add buildpacks but I got this warning when I tried to deploy:

```
App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz

Enumerating objects: 20, done.
Counting objects: 100% (20/20), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (20/20), 4.60 KiB | 1.15 MiB/s, done.
Total 20 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to rocky-journey-82706.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/rocky-journey-82706.git

No default language could be detected for this app.
```

Comment: Do you have a `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` committed to the root of your repository?

Comment: yep i have u can look github link i added.

Comment: On Stack Overflow questions should be self-contained. Generally speaking, we're not going to go off-site to find critical information. Having said that, I took a look and found that in fact you _don't_ have those files. I'll add an answer.

Comment: oh okay thx sorry for about rules. i am new about thats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gemfile` and `gemfile` are different things. Rename `gemfile` to `Gemfile` and `gemfile.lock` to `Gemfile.lock`, commit that change, and deploy again.

If you're using a filesystem that doesn't distinguish between those things (like most Windows filesystems) it might be tricky to do. See [Change case of a file on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1793735/354577)

Comment: i did it but its same. maybe is it about ruby version ? i use 2.6.3

Comment: i tried at 2.5.6 but its same. :(  have any other solution ?

Comment: You're getting exactly the same message?

Comment: And you're pushing commit `3501a54b` to Heroku's `master` branch?

Comment: what is 3501a54b ? i tried whats heroku's guide
i saw things about .git file i dont have that is it about that

Comment: ...that's the most recent commit you've published to GitHub. The code you're linking to.

Comment: wait what ? i m doing firstly clone github folders to my pc after that trying git push heroku master