# Git case sensitive Windows 7

Tags: git, staging, working-directory

I'm learning git so please forgive me if this has been answered before.  I added a file `README.txt` to the working directory. `git status` tells me that this is the only untracked file. I then ran `git add readme.txt`. Running `git status` now tells me once again that `README.txt` is the only untracked file. However, if I then run `git add README.txt` it now shows up as a new file.  Does this mean that git is adding a snapshot of the file `readme.txt` which doesn't exist? I don't understand as I thought that git was case insensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that git was case insensitive.

Not really. There's a config setting `core.ignorecase` which is normally set to true in Windows; the docs say

> If true, this option enables various workarounds to enable Git to work better 
>   on filesystems that are not case sensitive

But that's a long way from saying Git is case-insensitive. I reproduced what you did and I think you found a bug.

```
$ git checkout -b test 
Switched to a new branch 'test'

$ echo hello > README.txt

$ git status 
On branch test 
Untracked files:   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        README.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git add readme.txt

$ git status 
On branch test 
Untracked files:   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        README.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git diff --cached

$
```

One of two things should have happened: either Git should have complained that `readme.txt` didn't exist when I (and you) added it, or it should have added the contents of `README.txt` to the cache. It didn't do either of those things: no error from `git add` and no results listed by `git diff --cached`.

So my advice is treat Git commands as case-sensitive even when `core.ignorecase` is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

You have NTFS underneath which is case insensitive.  So if git asks if "README.txt" still exists, it is told "yes" even if you now have "readme.txt".

I would suggest telling git to forget completely about "README.txt" with

```
git rm --cached README.txt
```

and then add readme.txt again.

Comment: Not sure I follow. I understand windows ntfs is case insensitive. Are you saying that I need to input commands into git using case sensitivity? If i tell git to forget "README.txt", and then use `git add readme.txt` wouldn't I be in the same situation where the actual filename in the working directory is "README.txt" but git thinks it's "readme.txt". The actual filename is "README.txt" but entered it into git as "readme.txt".

Comment: Then reverse the instructions so it is "readme.txt" that is forgotten.  This happens on OS X too which has HFS.  If you want git to work its best then use Linux (or a good IDE).

Comment: I don't know if it could help be you can configure git to be case insensitive : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950/how-to-make-git-ignore-changes-in-case