# GIT: folder name sensitive issue

Tags: git

Our GIt Server repository is on Linux machine, and all clients are Windows machines.

one of the folder in our solution is "User Control" but sometimes when developer check-ins, it shows "user control" while check-in. after syncing to Server, server start showing two folders one with upper case and other with lower. now when other user take pull. they gets different kind of wired errors. files gets checked in randomly between these folder.

Please let me know what all settings i can do on server and client side to avoid it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make git ignore changes in case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950/how-to-make-git-ignore-changes-in-case)

Comment: Do any of the developers have a local folder with case different than in Git? If so they should correct the case of their local folder.

Comment: @scunliffe no i had double check it in past. its correct. everything is synced from remote repo which have right case. but this issue appears randomly. after 3-4 days.