# Stash (git) shows files in same folder with different casing

Tags: git

We currently have a problem in one of our projects where Stash (Atlassian's git) is pathing certain files to the `source` folder (lowercase) while everything else is under `Source` (capital).  The latter is the correct folder.

When we pull the source from the remote repo, there is only ever one folder.  This makes sense because we are working on Windows machines and the OS will prevent two folders that differ only by case.  Unfortunately, when we attempt to merge branches, files in the lowercase path are perceived as deleted so the merge tool (Visual Studio) attempts to delete them.  One of them is a .csproj file so you can imagine the harm this does!

We cannot figure out how this happened nor can we figure out how to undo it so all files are pathed correctly.  As a result, every time we think we have it fixed, it happens again.

Any ideas what caused it and what we can do to resolve?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950/how-to-make-git-ignore-changes-in-case

Comment: can you `git rm` the folder,  `git commit` and then `git add` it back in the following commit with the case specified?

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink, that appears to have fixed the problem.  Post your suggestion and an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @SethMcClaine, the folder already exists in its capitalized form.  That is the crux of the problem - there are TWO folders differing only by case.  We've already played the game of moving the affected files from "source" to "Source" and removing the "source" folder only to have it pop back up after a Pull Request is merged.  Somewhere in the git configuration, it is storing the fact that these files belong in the "source" folder instead of "Source".  I've applied the suggestions Jonathan.Brink referenced and it seems to have abated the problem for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ignorecase](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) setting. You can set this globally like this:

```
git config --global core.ignorecase true
```

> **core.ignoreCase**
>   If true, this option enables various workarounds to
>   enable Git to work better on filesystems that are not case sensitive,
>   like FAT. For example, if a directory listing finds "makefile" when
>   Git expects "Makefile", Git will assume it is really the same file,
>   and continue to remember it as "Makefile".