# why git merge replace the file automatically

Tags: git

I am writing a project with cpp. when I use `git merge other_branch` I concur a wired problem:

On my branch `My`, there is a header file `Foo.h` in `${PROJECT_ROOT}` directory，on the branch I want to merge `other_branch`, there is a header file `foo.h` in `${PROJECT_ROOT}`. `Foo.h` and `foo.h` have different content, when I use the `git merge other_branch` on `My` branch, git replace `Foo.h` with `foo.h`. In fact, the `Foo.h`  disappear, only  `foo.h` header file exists in `${PROJECT_ROOT}`. To fix the conflict， I rename `foo.h` to `Foo.h` and change the content, after fixing the problem, I use `git add .` and `git commit -m "..."` to finish the merge. After doing this, I use `git status` to see my workspace condition, I find that `Foo.h` is not staged for commit. So I use `git add Foo.h` to staged the file but nothing happen, `Foo.h` is still not staged for commit, it's wired.

I want to know:

1. why git replace `Foo.h` with `foo.h` instead of reporting the conflict?
2. why doesn't `git add .` work?

PS. When I see the remote repository, I find `Foo.h` and `foo.h` all exist. and my operating system is MacOS.

My conclusion is: git is case sensitive and MacOS's files are case insensitive, git actually want to keep `foo.h` and `Foo.h` but OSX regards `Foo.h` and `foo.h` as one file, so only `foo.h` exist, when I rename `foo.h` to `Foo.h` git still regard `Foo.h` as `foo.h`, thus when I use `git add Foo.h`, git add `foo.h` actually, so the `Foo.h` in git become a phantom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even a single operating system may support filesystems with case-sensitive and case-insensitive filenames.

Although, with a lot of work, it should be possible to determine whether the underlying filesystem, where the particular `git` repository lives, uses case-sensitive or case-insensitive filenames, for whatever reason this is not implementrf in the version of `git` you're using and it is your responsibility to configure `git` accurately. The `core.ignorecase` configuration setting tells git whether the underlying filesystem is case-sensitive or case-insensitive, and should be set accordingly.

It's reasonable to expect that a pre-built `git` package for a particular operating system would come pre-installed and configured with sensible defaults for the operating system. So, if an operating system uses mostly case-insensitive filenames then it would be reasonable to expect that the pre-built `git` package for the operating system would be set up accordingly. But, from the looks of it, for whatever the reason, this did not happen in your case.

If `git` is configured for case-sensitive filenames then `git` will continue with its business accordingly, and the resulting chips will fall where they may.

> why git replace Foo.h with foo.h instead of reporting the conflict?

Because `git` adopted The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: the computer always does exactly what you tell it to do instead of what you wanted it to do. This now becomes: `git` always does exactly what you tell it to do instead of what you want it to do.

In this case you told `git` to create or merge `foo.h`. So, git proceeded and created the file `foo.h`. Your operating system followed `git`'s instructions and clobbered the existing `Foo.h` file.

> why doesn't git add . work?

Because, at this point, things are hopelessly nonsensical.

The way for you to go forward would be [to set `core.ignoreCase` globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950/how-to-make-git-ignore-changes-in-case), and then proceed with a fresh checkout.

Comment: well, I use `git config --global core.ignorecases true` to make git case insensitive, and I even clone the same project, unfortunately, when I use `git status`, the problem still exist.

Comment: It is not called `core.ignorecases`. It is not called `core.ignorecase` either, for that matter. It is called `core.ignoreCase`. Don't ignore this case.

Comment: Don't try to set `core.ignorecase` globally: every repository has a *local* setting, so the global setting will be ignored anyway. (The local setting is determined by probing the file system's behavior at the time Git creates the repository.)

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion is mostly correct: *Git* is case sensitive and *your particular* macOS file system is case-insensitive.  However, macOS can work with case-sensitive file systems, and that's the way to go when merging in this repository.  [Here is how to create a case-sensitive macOS disk image on any existing volume, and then use that to work with Git.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59516454/1256452)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Git operates in a case-sensitive way.  This is the proper behaviour, since it's impossible to correctly case-fold text in a locale-insensitive way.  However, you're on a file system that's case insensitive, and so Git simply cannot check out both files at once since your file system can't support that.

The reason that Git doesn't warn about this with `git merge` is because different file systems fold case differently.  In fact, the case-folding algorithm can depend on the version of the OS under which the file system was formatted.  Unfortunately, no operating systems expose the case-folding algorithm to userspace, so Git cannot know what case-folding algorithm is in use, if any.

Git *can* detect this on a fresh clone because there are no existing files, so if it overwrites a file, then there must have been a conflict.  However, this doesn't work when a working tree already exists.

Note that Git does automatically detect whether a file system is case insensitive and sets `core.ignoreCase` for the repository if that's the case.  You should not modify this setting or set it globally because that breaks Git's autodetection.  However, this still doesn't let Git detect all case folding problems because it simply can't.

If you want to work with this repository, you need to either create yourself a case-sensitive APFS volume or use a Linux or other non-macOS Unix VM to do so.